# My Powershell loop is overwriting the previous excel entry. Using Export-CSV -append duplicates entries

Tags: sorting, csv, powershell, append, overwrite

Powershell is definitely not one of my "strengths" but every once in a while I try to script something to automate a manual task.  Anyway, here is my problem.  The script as is WORKS and WILL export a csv file and sort by the Hostname header.  My issues is there has got to be a better way of doing this?

```
#Clear the output screen
cls

#set the working directory to where the script and text files are located (must be same directory)
$scriptdir = Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath
cd $scriptdir

#set fileNamePaths for Export-Csv No Sort and Sorted to excel
$FilePathNS = "D:\PowerShell_Scripts\HP_Inventory\OAInfoAll_NoSort.csv"
$FilePathSort = "D:\PowerShell_Scripts\HP_Inventory\OAInfoAll.csv"

#set up the ip subnet import
$path = ".\EnclosureSubnets.txt"
$ip = Get-Content $path

#Loop to find OA information
foreach ($subnet in $ip) {

    $OAS = Find-HPOA $subnet -Timeout 250 -Verbose
    $OAS | where {$_.Role -eq "Active"} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append $FilePathNS
}

#Sort AOInfoAll.csv by hostname
Import-Csv $FilePathNS | Sort-Object Hostname | Export-Csv $FilePathSort -NoTypeInformation
```

If I take out the append then the loop will overwrite the previous entry and I will only end up with 2 IPs and 2 Hostnames.  Append fixes this BUT when I run the script again I get duplicate/repeating entries.

Also, I've tried using the Sort-Object Hostname inside the loop but it only sorts each individual entry as they are written. Here is an example (IPs and Hostnames are made up):

```
IP                  Hostname
192.168.1.10        chassis03
192.168.1.12        chassis05
192.168.2.16        chassis01
192.168.2.18        chassis02
192.168.3.14        chassis07
192.168.3.16        chassis08
```

So while my script works I'd like some feedback from "The Pros"  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't export inside your loop, instead capture all capture all OAS in a variable and sort that before outputting to a CSV.

```
foreach ($subnet in $ip) {

    [array]$OAS += Find-HPOA $subnet -Timeout 250 -Verbose

}

$OAS | Where{$_.Role -eq 'Active'} | Sort Hostname | Export-Csv $FilePathSort -NoTypeInformation
```

That dramatically reduces the number of disk reads/writes.